# CLLocationManager - fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: cllocationmanager, swift2, xcode7, clgeocoder

I have a little problem with CLLocationManager. When I click on IBAction "addPlace", the app crash. I don't see the problem, and I don't understand why the app crash.

Thank you in advance for your response.

```
class Map: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    // Outlets

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var BTNAdd: UIButton!

    // Variables

    var positionManager = CLLocationManager()
    var geoCoder : CLGeocoder!
    var placemark : CLPlacemark!

    var name: String = ""
    var address: String = ""
    var longitude: String = ""
    var latitude: String = ""

    // Actions

    @IBAction func myPosition(sender: AnyObject) {

        positionManager.delegate = self
        positionManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        positionManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        positionManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        mapView.showsUserLocation = true

    }

    @IBAction func addPlace(sender: AnyObject) {

            ///////////////////////////////////////
            // BUG HERE
            ///////////////////////////////////////

            let locality = String(self.placemark.locality)
            let postalCode = String(self.placemark.postalCode)
            let administrativeArea = String(self.placemark.administrativeArea)
            let country = String(self.placemark.country)

            print(locality + postalCode + administrativeArea + country)

            ///////////////////////////////////////
            ///////////////////////////////////////

    }

    // Functions

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in

            if let pm = placemarks?.first {
                self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
            }
        })

    }

    func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark?) {
        if let containsPlacemark = placemark {

            positionManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

            let locality = (containsPlacemark.locality != nil) ? containsPlacemark.locality : ""
            let postalCode = (containsPlacemark.postalCode != nil) ? containsPlacemark.postalCode : ""
            let administrativeArea = (containsPlacemark.administrativeArea != nil) ? containsPlacemark.administrativeArea : ""
            let country = (containsPlacemark.country != nil) ? containsPlacemark.country : ""

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add the variables in class, and fix my IBAction

```
var locality: String = ""
var postalCode: String = ""
var administrativeArea: String = ""
var country: String = ""

@IBAction func addPlace(sender: AnyObject) {

    let locality = self.locality
    let postalCode = self.postalCode
    let administrativeArea = self.administrativeArea
    let country = self.country

    print(locality + postalCode + administrativeArea + country)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `placemark` variable is declared as an explicitly unwrapped optional, but since you get this error message it's obvious that sometimes this variable will be nil.

Change the declaration to make it a normal Optional, then use `if let` to ensure safe unwrapping and handle errors:

```
var placemark : CLPlacemark?

@IBAction func addPlace(sender: AnyObject) {

        if let mark = placemark {
            let locality = String(self.mark.locality)
            let postalCode = String(self.mark.postalCode)
            let administrativeArea = String(self.mark.administrativeArea)
            let country = String(self.mark.country)
            print(locality + postalCode + administrativeArea + country)
        } else {
            print("placemark was nil")
        }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I have an error in placemark: reference to property 'placemark' in closure requires 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit. If I add self.placemark, and delete the others self, there are not errors, but only 'placemark was nil' display.

Comment: You're welcome. And that was the goal: handle the error to stop your app crashing. :) If you see the line "placemark was nil" this is because, well, *the placemark was nil*. It answers your question which was "I don't see the problem, and I don't understand why the app crash." Now you see and understand: an explictly unwrapped optional which was nil.